# FreeRTOS I2C Definition

Tags: i2c, freertos

I am trying to introduce an I2C communication in an NXP SDK program which I can edit in MCUXpresso. I have searched for different functions and found this one. The issue is that I know how to define the first to parameters, but I´m unable to figure out how to use or define the last parameter `void *callbackParam`.

```c
HAL_I2cSlaveTransferInstallCallback(hal_i2c_slave_handle_t handle, hal_i2c_slave_transfer_callback_t callback, void *callbackParam)
```

I´m also struggling to create an I2C task, I assume this function is the one I was looking for, but I´m not sure.

Comment: It's a traditional way on how to pass the parameter to the callback function itself. Show the prototype of your second parameter and you will see what you need to supply as the last one.